# Retrieve all children of Base page type

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-apiv2

I'm working on a Wagtail app which has a number of different page types RawHTMLLandingPage, MarketingLandingPage, etc. which are children of a base page, LandingPageBase.

If I understand correctly, a child page type knows what type it's parent is. But is it possible for a parent to programmatically know about it's children?

When we're requesting a landing page, we don't already know what type it is (other than a 'landing page' until it hits the API and we query the database).

```
class LandingPageBase(Page):
    pass

    def identify_children(self):
        # Can I find out about the two children from this method?
        pass

class RawHTMLLandingPage(LandingPageBase):
    pass


class MarketingLandingPage(LandingPageBase):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `get_page_models` function in `wagtail.core.models` which returns all classes that descend from `Page`, so it would be possible to filter that list to just the ones that are subclasses of a given parent:

```
from wagtail.core.models import get_page_models

class LandingPageBase(Page):
    @classmethod
    def identify_children(cls):
        return [model for model in get_page_models() if issubclass(model, cls)]
```